# Complex Analysis-Maximum Modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been given the following problem,

If $f$ is an entire function with $f(z)=f(z+2)=f(z+i)$ for each $z \in \Bbb C $ show that f is constant.

I think it suffices to show that f is constant in the disc centred at 0 with radius 2 since $f(z)=f(z+2n+mi)$ for $m,n \in \Bbb Z $

And since the restriction of the function to that disk is analytic can be straight away say that f is constant in the disk.?

Answer (score 2):

Consider the rectangle
$$\{a+bi\in\Bbb C: 0\le a\le 6, 0\le b\le 3\}$$

Now draw a grid with vertical lines at $a=2$ and $a=4$, and horizontal lines at $b=1$ and $b=2$.

By the Maximum Modulus Principle, the maximum of $|f|$ in this rectangle is achieved in its border, say at $w$. No matter in which side is $w$, we can find another maximum in the interior of the rectangle, over the lines of the grid. Then $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use [Liouville's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(complex_analysis)).
In particular, if an entire function has two linearly independent periods, then can it still be unbounded?

Comment: If you consider the compact disc and {$z| |z| \le 2$} we can say the  function i bounded in that disc right? since the image is compact and then Liouville's theorem can be applied to say its constant?

Comment: Instead of considering a compact disc, I would consider the rectangle spawned by $z \in [0,2]$ and $z \in [0,i]$. It is easy to see that $f$ is simply a repetition of that rectangle in every direction, hence it's bounded in the whole complex plane. Hence we can use Liouville's Theorem (by the way, doubly periodic holomorphic functions are called [Elliptic Curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve), and one of the first steps in that theory is to show that entire elliptic curves are bounded).

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is an elliptic function, meaning it is doubly-periodic. Doubly-periodic functions are either meromorphic or constant. Since you say $f$ is entire, it must be constant. I suggest you look at the Wikipedia page for elliptic functions.